# Finding all references dependent on an imported package in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, refactoring, python-import

I'm refactoring some legacy Python 2.7 code to use dependency injection with third party packages.

I have one package that will be factored into the first pass at dependency injection.

Is there a way that I can use Pycharm to find all variables and methods in the code that are in the imported package?

Comment: Do you want to find any items of package(I mean functions, classes etc/all possible imports)? Or specific item(method, class etc)?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Any items in package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all possible ways. But I can propose a few ways.

> **Note!** I don't know your hotkeys and OS(my hot keys may not work).

Here is an example of project:

```
/lagacy_pack
   __init__.py
   first.py
   second.py
app.py
```

`app.py`(depends on `legacy_pack`):

```
from legacy_pack.first import Test
from legacy_pack.second import get_name, global_name
# some logic...
name = get_name('test')
if name != global_name:
    inst = Test()
```

`/legacy_pack/first.py`:

```
class Test(object):
    # just for demonstration
    pass
```

`/legacy_pack/second.py`:

```
def get_name(name):  # type: (str) -> str
    return '.'.join(['name', ':', name])
# just for demonstration
global_name = get_name('example')
```

**1)** This method is good if the package is small. The easiest way to find all links to `legacy_pack` is using `Find in Path...` by imports(`shift + cmd + f`). How to do using mouse:

- Right click project folder -> **Find in Path...**
- Find `from legacy_pack` and `import legacy_pack`

You will see all files which include your package. Example:

[image: find by path]

**2)** If you have really large package I recommend you to do it step by step.

In some cases we need to rename something(class, method etc). You can do it safely using PyCharm. Let's rename `class Test` to `class Docker`. Set carriage to `Test`, `shift + F6`(using mouse: right click on `Test` -> Refactor -> Rename -> enter `Docker` -> click on refactor. Check imports in `app.py`. `from legacy_pack.first import Test` was changed to `from legacy_pack.first import Docker`

[image: rename]

In some cases we need to remove something. So, we need to find out where we use what we want to delete. Click on 'something'(method, variable, class etc), `alt + F8`(using mouse: right click -> `Find usages`. In the bottom panel you will see all usages of 'something' by modules.

[image: usages]

Also I can recommend to use:

right click(on method, variable etc) -> Refactor -> `Change Signature`, `Move`, `Extract`.

right click(on folder/directory) -> `Replace in Path...`

(`alt + ctrl + o`) Optimize imports

**3)** If you want to see tree of dependencies by module/package I can recommend [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/). How to use:

```
# pylint path_to_module_or_package --reports=y
pylint ./app.py --reports=y
```

You will see something like this:

[image: tree]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, you put a lot of effort into your answer. Thank you!  I'm afraid that my OP wasn't very clear.  I'm looking for a way that I can use Pycharm to find all variables and methods in the code that are in the imported package.  I've edited the OP to make this clearer.

Comment: @empty thanks. In any case you will do something in parts. Therefore -> `find usages` ))) good luck ;)